# Gradle project sync failed for adding any dependency - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to compile 'compile .android...' any dependicies from my last update , After some update like Android support library, android support repository , sdk platform tools in SDK manager. I am unable to add dependency, whenever i add it shows below error

[image: .]

And If i change my dependency compiled like this to latest As

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

it shows like this :
[image: sa]

So please solve my problem i m unable to work with android studio, say ur suggestions for above.

Comment: change the version @User Android

Comment: what's your compilation version of android in gradle?

Comment: @pRaNaY My compile version is 21. build version also 21.x

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this folder exist 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools on your machine. If it does not, y advice is to remove Android studio and reinstall it. Note: The binary version and not the Archived version of AS

Answer (score 0):

[image]

do u set compileSdkVersion 23 and buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"?

Answer (score 0):

Update android SDK to latest version 23 and see that your gradle file content is similar to below

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "yur id"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```